# ConcurrentHashMap returns null if I remove the very next object

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to understand how a failsafe iterator works. I encountered something strange in concurrent hashmap. The code is as follows --

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> hm = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("name1", "value1");
    hm.put("name2", "value2");
    hm.put("name3", "value3");

    Iterator<String> itr = hm.keySet().iterator();
    int index = 0;
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(hm.get(itr.next()));
        hm.put(index+"1", index+"2");
        hm.remove("name2");
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println("--- Second iteration --- ");
    Iterator<String> itr2 = hm.keySet().iterator();
    while(itr2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(hm.get(itr2.next()));
    }
```

which prints :

```
    value3
    null
    value1
    --- Second iteration --- 
    12
    02
    value3
    value1
    22
```

I'm confused why removing an element in the first case was updated while addition is not! I'm using 1.8 runtime environment.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will or will not see changes you perform while Iterating. Whether you see it will depend on which how far you have iterated and where the key would be placed in the internal data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Iterator for ConcurrentHashMap navigates the underlying data structure in a way which is thread safe.  It does this as a single pass and if a key/entry which it has "passed" it won't see that change. If a change occurs beyond the point which the Iterator has reached, it might see that change if it doesn't change again before it gets there.  Here is an example;

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    map.put(i, true);
System.out.println(map.keySet());
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Map<Integer, Boolean> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
    map2.put(ints.get(i), false);
System.out.println("All evens " + map2.keySet());
// all evens
Iterator<Integer> iter = map2.keySet().iterator();
for (int i = 8; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    // remove evens and add odds
    map2.remove(ints.get(8 - i));
    map2.remove(ints.get(i));
    map2.put(ints.get(i + 1), false);
    System.out.println(iter.next() +" - full set is: "+map2.keySet());
}
while (iter.hasNext())
    System.out.println(iter.next());
System.out.println("All odds " + map2.keySet());
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
All evens [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
0 - full set is: [2, 4, 6, 9]
2 - full set is: [4, 7, 9]
4 - full set is: [5, 7, 9]
5 - full set is: [3, 5, 7, 9]
7 - full set is: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
9
All odds [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Note how the keys the iterator sees if NOT the keys set at any given moment.  Instead changes which occur after (in this case higher numbers) are visible, but keys which are in it's past (in this case lower numbers) are not.

Comment: Incredible example! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the iterators of `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when the Map is edited.

Instead of throwing this exception, this map will return keys/values reflecting that existed at some timespan since the iterator is created, and the current time. This is also stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

If you need to use the value and keys at the same time, without causing bugs like this, you should loop over the map's entryset instead the keyset, this can be done with the following:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> itr = hm.entrySet().iterator();
int index = 0;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> next = itr.next();
    System.out.println(next.getValue());
    hm.put(index+"1", index+"2");
    hm.remove("name2");
    index++;
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that a snapshot is taken (Unlike CopyOnWriteArrayList/Set) Any change which occurs while Iterating many or may not be visible.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are you sure? It says it in its javadoc: "Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements **reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation** of the iterator/enumeration"

Comment: The Itertator doesn't take a copy of the collection nor is it atomic, (so there is no performance hit for large collections, and no risk of a memory leak) this means that while iterating your could see a set of keys for example which the map never had at a any given moment.

Comment: I just added 3 more key value pairs to the CHashMap which gave enough time to the iterator and my output is as follows :

        value6,
        value5,
        02,
        value4,
        value3,
        value1,
        42,
        32,
        22

So, I guess Iterator also gets updated but we never know when!

Comment: @Jay the Iterator scans through the segments and data structure in a way which allows for changes to be performed on it concurrently.  If a change occurs in part of the data structure it has already scanned, you won't see that until you run a new Iterator, if the change occurred after it, you will see the change.

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterLawrey.. I'm writing a blog on fail fast iterators so performing some crazy experiments. Your answer helped me to get a better understanding of it and I'm borrowing your lines.

Comment: @Jay please see my answer where I illustrate what I mean.